# View Controller continues to load xib file after update

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have created an update to my app, that was using a xib file for loading one particular View Controller. In an update I have deleted that `xib` and removed all outlets from source file of a controller. Now I create my controller this way:

```
RRVacancySearchViewController *vacancySearchController = [[RRVacancySearchViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

When I run **an updated version over an old version** on iPhone, this controller fails to load with an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RRVacancySearchViewController 0x1fdaaa20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _historyTableView.'
```

But I do not have a `_historyTableView` anymore. It is loaded from an old `xib` file, that I do not want to be used anymore.

What should I make to make iPhone forget completely about that `xib` and do not use it?

Comment: Delete the app from the device. Xcode does not delete files during deployment. If you want to test the update process you have to use ad hoc deployment. You can't just hit Run from Xcode.

Comment: This is correct answer. After creating Ad Hoc version the problem stopped to occur. Installing an update from Xcode is not relevant for testing updates.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `.xib` in your project and remove all references to it. Also confirm in your code you are not looking for the `_historyTableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that you still have an IBOutlet refering to the _historyTableView, in your xib file

Answer (score 0):

Some times the simulator **doesn't refresh new xib files / images** to make the test process faster. 
I've experienced this problem a lot of times and the only solution I've found is to reset Simulator, deleting the application manually, and reinstalling it.

If you need to check the different, you have to build two different ipa and to install them manually.